# Exploding a JSON array in a Spark Dataset

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataset

I am using Spark 2.1 and Zeppelin 0.7 to do the following. (this is inspired by the Databricks tutorial (https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html))

I have created the following schema

```
val jsonSchema = new StructType()
.add("Records", ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("Id", IntegerType)
    .add("eventDt", StringType)
    .add("appId", StringType)
    .add("userId", StringType)
    .add("eventName", StringType)
    .add("eventValues", StringType)
   )
  )
```

to read in the following json 'array' file, which i have in my 'inputPath' directory

```
{
"Records": [{
    "Id": 9550,
    "eventDt": "1491810477700",
    "appId": "dandb01",
    "userId": "985580",
    "eventName": "OG: HR: SELECT",
    "eventValues": "985087"
    },
    ... other records
]}

val rawRecords = spark.read.schema(jsonSchema).json(inputPath)
```

I then want to explode these records to get to the individual events

```
val events = rawRecords.select(explode($"Records").as("record"))
```

But rawRecords.show() and events.show() are both null.

Any idea what i am doing wrong? In the past i know i should be using JSONL for this, but the Databricks tutorial suggests that the latest version of spark should now support json arrays.

Comment: Actually your code works. It is your json file. Spark does not like formatted JSON. Try to format a one liner json and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following :

1. I have a file foo.txt with below data

> {"Records":[{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"}]}
>   {"Records":[{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"},{"Id":9550,"eventDt":"1491810477700","appId":"dandb01","userId":"985580","eventName":"OG:HR:SELECT","eventValues":"985087"}]}

2. I have the following code

   import sqlContext.implicits._ 
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val df = sqlContext.read.json("foo.txt")   df.printSchema()
     df.select(explode($"Records").as("record")).show
3. I get the following output

> root  |-- Records: array (nullable = true)  |    |-- element: struct
>   (containsNull = true)  |    |    |-- Id: long (nullable = true)  |
>   |    |-- appId: string (nullable = true)  |    |    |-- eventDt:
>   string (nullable = true)  |    |    |-- eventName: string (nullable =
>   true)  |    |    |-- eventValues: string (nullable = true)  |    |
>   |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
>
> ```
> +--------------------+
> |              record|
> +--------------------+
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> |[9550,dandb01,149...|
> +--------------------+
> ```